# Attempting to send/receive over Process Pipe to python wrapper, c++ code

Tags: python, c++, multiprocessing, pipe, wrapper

I have a python wrapper holding some c++ code. In it is a function that I setup as a process from my python code. Its a while statement that I need to setup a condition for when it should shut down.

For this situation , the while statement is simple.

```
while(TERMINATE == 0)
```

I have data that is being sent back from within the while loop. I'm using pipe() to create 'in' and 'out' objects. I send the 'out' object to the function when I create the process.

```
fxn = self.FG.do_videosequence
(self.inPipe, self.outPipe) = Pipe()
self.stream = Process(target=fxn, args=(self.outPipe,))
self.stream.start()
```

As I mentioned, while inside the wrapper I am able to send data back to the python script with

```
PyObject *send = Py_BuildValue("s", "send_bytes");
PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pipe, send, temp, NULL);
```

This works just fine. However, I'm having issues with sending a message to the C++ code, in the wrapper, that tells the loop to stop.

What I figured I would do is just check poll(), as that is what I do on the python script side. I want to keep it simple. When the system sees that there is an incoming signal from the python script it would set TERMINATE = 1. so i wrote this.

```
PyObject *poll = Py_BuildValue("p", "poll");
```

As I'm expecting a true or false from the python function poll(). I figured "p" would be ideal as it would convert true to 1 and false to 0.

in the loop I have

```
if(PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pipe, poll, NULL, NULL))
            TERMINATE = 1;
```

I wanted to use poll() as its non-blocking, like recv() is. This way I could just go about my other work and check poll() once a cycle.

however, when I send a signal from the python script it never trips.

```
self.inPipe.send("Hello");
```

I'm not sure where the disconnect is. When I print the poll() request, I get 0 the entire time. I'm either not calling it correctly, and its just defaulting to 0. or I'm not actually generating a signal to trip the poll() call. Thus its always 0.

Does anyone have any insight as what i am doing wrong?

*****UPDATE******

I found some other information.

```
PyObject *poll = Py_BuildValue("p", "poll");
```

should be

```
PyObject *poll = Py_BuildValue("s", "poll");
```

as I'm passing a string as a reference to the function im calling it should be referenced as a string. It has nothing to do with the return type.

From there the return of

```
PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pipe, poll, NULL, NULL)
```

is a pyobject so it needs to be checked against a pyobject. such as making a call to

```
PyObject_IsTrue
```

to determine if its true or false. I'll make changes to my code and if I have solution I'll update the post with an answer.

Comment: I'm confused by your code.  You do realize that you'd need two pipes ... that's four file descriptors ... to handle bi-directional communications.  Right?

The pair of descriptors returned by a call to pipe() (the system call) include both ends of a pipe; one will be used by the parent and the other by a child process.  Two calls to pipe with the parent keeping one type each and child using the corresponding, opposite ends of each, gets you bi-directional pairs of pipes.

Also be sure you're I/O is non-blocking on at least one end of each!  Otherwise deadlock is likely.

Comment: @JimDennis Hi, thanks for that. I've updated my post to reflect your thoughts. I also posted some new information I 've been able to find.

Comment: @JimDennis Jim, maybe you can clarify. I just checked the python docs and it says that the pipe() function defaults to two ways, duplexed. The examples that it gives seems to represent that four descriptors would not be needed. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Pipe

Comment: Note: I specifically referred to the Unix/Linux system call for pipe() ... but the Python os.pipe() has similar semantics: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.pipe#os.pipe.  I don't know what docs you're reading. (Are they for the C level Python API?)

But perhaps this discussion will be useful for you: https://claytonrichey.com/post/c-cpp-python-pipe/

Part of my confusion is that I've barely ever used the C API to Python;

Answer (score 0):

So I've been able to find the solution. In the end I was making two mistakes. 
The first mistake was when I created the pyobject reference to the python function I was calling. I mistook the information and inserted a "p" thinking before reading the context. So

```
PyObject *poll = Py_BuildValue("p", "poll");
```

should be

```
PyObject *poll = Py_BuildValue("s", "poll");
```

The second mistake was how I was handling the return value of

```
PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pipe, poll, NULL, NULL)
```

while its true that its calling a python object, it is not returning a simple true false value, but rather a python object. So I specificly needed to handle the python object, by calling

```
PyObject_IsTrue(Pyobject o)
```

with the return of the poll() request as the argument. I now have the ability to send/recieve from both the python script and the C api contained in the wrapper.